# Password in activation email

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

is it somehow possible to put the users password into an activation email?

I have an email template I want to put the password in so the user knows there initial password.

But the password property is directly hashed and not available in cleartext so I can put it into the email. Also I don't want to have an extra property e.g. clearPassword which then would get stored in the db (even it is maybe for a short time). I searched for transient attributes but this seems not to be possible at the moment.

Any tips how I can archive an activation email with the initial password in it?

Comment: "_is it somehow possible to put the users password..._" Yes, but DON'T DO THIS! ;)

Comment: Something I hate about activation emails is when they have my password there!. You NEVER might know my password.

Comment: Another approach I think of is to allow the user to set his own password after activation. But a user must have a password initially and I didn't find a possibility to create a one time auth token. The problem is the users are not created by the user himself. An administrator creates them.

Comment: Send them an activation link which points them to a site where they can create their password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for someone how struggles with the same issue here is what I have done:

At first to be able to create users without a password I generate one before the user is saved.

```
User.observe('before save', function(ctx, next) {
    var model = (ctx.instance) ? ctx.instance : ctx.data;

    if (!model.password) {
        //generate short random password
        model.password = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8);
    }

    next();
});
```

Then I have implemented my own method to activate the user:

```
/**
 * 
 * Activates the user account and sets the new password.
 * 
 */
User.activate = function(credentials, cb) {
    //check if email and token was provided
    if (!credentials.email || !credentials.verificationToken) {
         var crednetialsErr = "Email or token are invalid. Please check your inputs.";
         return cb(crednetialsErr, false);
    }

    //find the user with the given informations
    User.findOne({
        where: {
            and: [
                {email: credentials.email},
                {verificationToken: credentials.verificationToken}
            ] 
        } 
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            //error occured while find the user object
            return cb(err, false);
        }

        if (!user) {
            //no user was found
            var crednetialsErr = "Email or verificationToken are invalid. Please check your inputs.";
            return cb(crednetialsErr, false);
        }

        //set the new password
        user.password = credentials.password;

        user.save(function(err, user) {
            var redirectUrl = '/';

            if (err) {
                cb(err, false);
            }

            //confirms the user account and activates it
            User.confirm(user.id, credentials.verificationToken, redirectUrl, function(err) {
                cb(err, true);
            });
        });
    });
};


/**
 * 
 * Description of the new activate remote function.
 * 
 */
User.remoteMethod(
    'activate', 
    {
      description: 'Activates the user and sets the given password',
      accepts: [
          {
              arg: 'credentials',
              type: 'object',
              required: true,
              http: {
                  source: 'body'
              },
              description: 'Must contains \'email\',\'verificationToken\' and \'password\' key.'
          },
      ],
      returns: {arg: "success", type: 'bool'},
      http: {
          verb: "post" 
      }
    }
);
```